# Where did the forecast.Holtwinters go in R 3.4.3?

Tags: r, holtwinters

I'm using R Studio based on R 3.4.3. However, when I tried to call the forecast.HoltWinters function, R told me that "could not find function "forecast.HoltWinters"". Inspect the installed package (v8.2) told me that it's true, there is no forecast.HoltWinters. But the manual in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/ clearly stated that forecast.HoltWinters is still available.

I have also tried stats::HoldWinters, but it's working wrong. The code run fine on another computer, but it couldn't run at all on mine. Is there any solution?

Here is the code. Book2.csv has enough data to last more than 3 periods.

```
dltt <- read.csv("book2.csv", header = TRUE)
dltt.ts <- ts(dltt$Total, frequency=12, start=c(2014,4))
dltt.ts.hw <- HoltWinters(dltt.ts)
library(forecast)
dltt.ts.hw.fc <- forecast.HoltWinters(dltt.ts.hw) //Error as soon as I run this line
```

Comment: remove the package and reinstall; any change?

Comment: Nope, nothing changed at all.

Comment: try `forecast:::forecast.HoltWinters`

Comment: Don't use ::: notation to try and access unexported functions without a really good reason. There is no good reason here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fit a HoltWinters model using the `HoltWinters` function and then use `forecast`. Its all in the help for `HoltWinters` and `forecast`, namely `"The function invokes particular _methods_  which depend on the class of the first argument"`. I'll copy the guts of it here:

```
m <- HoltWinters(co2)
forecast(m)
```

Note this will call the non-exported `forecast.HoltWinters` function, which you should *never* call directly using triple-colon notation as some may suggest.

Comment: Still, while this answer allow me to bypass the problem, I still don't understand why does function forecast.HoltWinters didn't load correctly?

Comment: `forecast.HoltWinters` is an *S3 method* of the generic `forecast` function. When you run `forecast(x)` it calls the correct method for whatever `x` is. In this case, `x` is a `HoltWinters` thing, so `forecast.HoltWinters` gets called.  Suppose you change your mind and want to fit an Arima model instead, you fit it with `Arima(...)` and you dont have to change `forecast.HotlWinters` to `forecast.Arima` everywhere. Its the S3 Object Oriented system.